# On postfix how do I override the mydomain value in PHP

Tags: php, postfix, email

In my postfix log I have the following when I send e-mail from a PHP based web site:

> Feb 11 11:52:04 cp5
>   postfix/qmgr[6007]: 93C6E79C4D1:
>   from=|www-data@domain.com|,
>   size=3266, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

(I substituted | for smaller-than / greater-than signs.)

The problem with the above is that I need to control the "FROM:" address. I know I can control the "@domain.com" address by modifying the "mydomain" in Postfix main.cf file and I had to do that in order to stop e-mail from bouncing in the first place. The problems is now people are reply to "www-data@domain.com" and I don't want that.

This is a Plesk 9.5  server which as far as I know runs a stock standard Postfix installation. I would like advice on how to fix this problem in my PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you can do from your PHP script:

Have a look at Examaple #2 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This example also gives you control over the Reply-To headers. There's no need to touch anything in Postfix!

Answer (score 2):

Use -f option(sender address):

```
<?php
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

Comment: +1 Adding "-f" to the mail() function in PHP is easier then writing out all your headers by hand.